# Unreal Engine 5: Wheeled vehicle rotation issue

Tags: rotation, unreal-engine5

[problematic scene which car-body rotate together with wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4POjq.jpg)

I try to create a driving simulation in Unreal Engine 5.
When I increase the speed of the wheel-rotation, the connected car-body (yellow part) rotate together with the wheels. It causes same issue, when I steer the wheel left/right.

How can I rotate only the wheel without rotating together the connected car-bdody?

Attached screenshot is the problematic scene, which the connected yellow body rotate together with wheel rotation.

I´m curius if it is the problem with imported 3D meshes, which I created in Blender, or if I can fix it in the Unreal engine. I hope it can be fixed in Unreal Engine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior. You might want to use Unity for doing this or recreate your meshes with Blender.

Comment: Thank you, do you know what should I change when I recreate the meshes in Blender? I´d try it again in UE5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).